# How to create resource folder for android 21 api and higher?

Tags: android, android-resources

I can create folders with names values-21, values-22. But It will produce code duplication. Can I create something like values-21>= ?

Comment: creating a folder `values-21` will support 21 and up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For API 21+, you would have res/values-v21 . Take a look here http://www.metaandroid.com/question/primary-dark-color-android-under-api-21/

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to have 2 values folder.

One that exist by default, and another, u have to create in your res folder and name it `values-v21`.

In the default values folder, in `styles.xml`, use theme other than Material theme And in the styles.xml of `values-v21` folder that you created, use Material theme.

Android phone will automatically pickup the `styles.xml` which it support. If the phone supports Material Design (Lollipop devices), your app will use material theme (values-21 folder).

if it doesnt (in phones running older android versions), the default values folder will be used.

For more reference go [click here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)